# Preventing System.StackOverflowException when creating Ackermann Function program

Tags: c#

This program ends in a overflow:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in ConsoleApplication3.exe

**How can I keep it going without crashing?**

I can only see up to `ack(4,0)`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + "," + j.ToString() + "=" + ack(i, j));
            }
        }
    }

    static int ack(int m,int n)
    {
        int ans;
        if (m == 0)
            ans = n + 1;
        else if (n == 0)
            ans = ack(m - 1, 1);
        else
            ans = ack(m - 1, ack(m, n - 1));
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: A question about a stack overflow.... on stackoverflow.  Excellent.

Comment: I got it from here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7sm9dzFtEI&t=314s

Comment: You should try to get `m` to `0`...

Comment: The [Ackermann Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) is *supposed* to get really huge really quickly.

Comment: If you somehow solve the `StackOverFlowException`, you will need a bigger variable than an `int`.  You'll want to check out [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You can try to imitate recursion calls by the stack structure, but I'm not sure that it very helps you for bigger value (your memory will end)

Comment: The important part here is "without crashing". A stack overflow exception cannot be handled. By its very definition, you've overflown the stack, any handling you want to do needs stack space. Can't be done. So you need to figure out a way to avoid the stack overflow to begin with, not how to handle it.

Comment: I wonder if Lippert applies tailcall optimization if you get rid of the single-return pattern and just return directly from each if block.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of the Ackermann function is that it grows absurdly quickly.  So you've picked possibly the worst function to deal with; it's intended to be pathological.  Even without a stack overflow, you will very quickly overflow the `int` data type anyway.

There is one thing you can do and that's to try and memoize the function:

```
public static int Ackermann( int m, int n )
{
    int result;
    if( !smCache.TryGetValue( ( m, n ), out result ) )
    {
        result = AckermannImpl( m, n );
        smCache.Add( ( m, n ), result );
    }

    return result;
}

private static int AckermannImpl( int m, int n )
{
    if( m == 0 )        return n + 1;
    else if( n == 0 )   return Ackermann( m - 1, 1 );
    else                return Ackermann( m - 1, Ackermann( m, n - 1 ) );
}

private static readonly Dictionary<(int, int), int> smCache = new Dictionary<(int, int), int>();
```

This can help reduce the amount of recursion required by avoiding computing the same values of the Ackermann function more than once.

Doing this I was able to evaluate Ack( 5, 0 ) and doing so resulted in 163847 evaluations of the `AckermannImpl` method.  Ack( 6, 0 ) still causes an overflow (and there's not much you can do about it).

Other answers have mentioned tail recursion but haven't shown exactly how to apply the transformation.  And for good reason: it's not terribly obvious how to do it because of that double recursion at the end.  It also doesn't completely remove the recursion (again, because of that double recursion).  But here's what a tail optimized version looks like:

```
private static int A( int m, int n )
{
    while( true )
    {
        if( m == 0 ) return n + 1;
        if( n == 0 )
        {
            m = m - 1;
            n = 1;
            continue;
        }

        n = A( m--, n - 1 );
    }
}
```

You can combine this approach with memoization (which will improve speed), but it won't really allow you to evaluate any arguments that the pure memoization approach couldn't do (mostly because those values are just too big). I suspect it might be able to if `BigInteger` is used, but I haven't tested that.

Comment: he says on the video he has it doing for 1 week and doesnt crash.

Comment: @xDDD because it is written in C++. Has different stack limitations than C#.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        for (long m = 0; m <= 10; ++m)
        {
            for (long n = 0; n <= 10; ++n)
            {
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                Console.WriteLine("Ackermann({0}, {1}) = {2}", m, n, Ackermann(m, n));
                Console.WriteLine("Time taken:{0}", DateTime.Now - now);
            }
        }
    }

    public class OverflowlessStack<T>
    {
        internal sealed class SinglyLinkedNode
        {
            private const int ArraySize = 2048;
            T[] _array;
            int _size;
            public SinglyLinkedNode Next;
            public SinglyLinkedNode()
            {
                _array = new T[ArraySize];
            }
            public bool IsEmpty { get { return _size == 0; } }
            public SinglyLinkedNode Push(T item)
            {
                if (_size == ArraySize - 1)
                {
                    SinglyLinkedNode n = new SinglyLinkedNode();
                    n.Next = this;
                    n.Push(item);
                    return n;
                }
                _array[_size++] = item;
                return this;
            }
            public T Pop()
            {
                return _array[--_size];
            }
        }
        private SinglyLinkedNode _head = new SinglyLinkedNode();

        public T Pop()
        {
            T ret = _head.Pop();
            if (_head.IsEmpty && _head.Next != null)
                _head = _head.Next;
            return ret;
        }
        public void Push(T item)
        {
            _head = _head.Push(item);
        }
        public bool IsEmpty
        {
            get { return _head.Next == null && _head.IsEmpty; }
        }
    }
    public static BigInteger Ackermann(BigInteger m, BigInteger n)
    {
        var stack = new OverflowlessStack<BigInteger>();
        stack.Push(m);
        while (!stack.IsEmpty)
        {
            m = stack.Pop();
        skipStack:
            if (m == 0)
                n = n + 1;
            else if (m == 1)
                n = n + 2;
            else if (m == 2)
                n = n * 2 + 3;
            else if (n == 0)
            {
                --m;
                n = 1;
                goto skipStack;
            }
            else
            {
                stack.Push(m - 1);
                --n;
                goto skipStack;
            }
        }
        return n;
    }
}
```

This will get you

```
(4,2) = 2003529930406846464979072351560255750447825475569751419265016973710894059556311453089506130880933348101038234342907263181822949382118812668869506364761547029165041871916351587966347219442930927982084309104855990570159318959639524863372367203002916969592156108764948889254090805911457037675208500206671563702366126359747144807111774815880914135742720967190151836282560618091458852699826141425030123391108273603843767876449043205960379124490905707560314035076162562476031863793126484703743782954975613770981604614413308692118102485959152380195331030292162800160568670105651646750568038741529463842244845292537361442533614373729088303794601274724958414864915930647252015155693922628180691650796381064132275307267143998158508811292628901134237782705567421080070065283963322155077831214288551675554073345107213112427399562982719769150054883905223804357045848197956393157853510018992000024141963706813559840464039472194016069517690156119726982337890017641517190051133466306898140219383481435426387306539552969691388024158161859561100640362119796101859534802787167200122604642492385111393400464351623867567078745259464670903886547743483217897012764455529409092021959585751622973333576159552394885297579954028471943529913543763705986928913757153740001986394332464890052543106629669165243419174691389632476560289415199775477703138064781342309596190960654591300890188887588084733625956065444888501447335706058817090162108499714529568344061979690565469813631162053579369791403236328496233046421066136200220175787851857409162050489711781820400187282939943446186224328009837323764931814789848119452713007440220765680910376203999203492023906626264491909167985461515778839060397720759279378852241294301017458086862263369284725851403039615558564330385450688652213114813638408384778263790459607186876728509763471271988890680478243230394718650525660978150729861141430305816927924971409161059417185352275887504477592218301158780701975535722241400019548102005661773589781499532325208589753463547007786690406429016763808161740550405117670093673202804549339027992491867306539931640720492238474815280619166900933805732120816350707634351669869625020969023162859350071874190579161241536897514808261904847946571736601005892476655445840838334790544144817684255327207315586349347605137419779525190365032198020108764738368682531025183377533908861426184800374008082238104076468878471647552945326947661700424461063311238021134588694532200116564076327023074292426051582811070387018345324567635625951430032037432740780879056283663406965030844225855967039271869461158513793386475699748568670079823960604393478850861649260304945061743412365828352144806726676841807083754862211408236579802961200027441324438432402331257403545019352428776430880232850855886089962774458164680857875115807014743763867976955049991643998284357290415378143438847303484261903388841494031366139854257635577105335580206622185577060082551288893332226436281984838613239570676191409638533832374343758830859233722284644287996245605476932428998432652677378373173288063210753211238680604674708428051166488709084770291208161104912555598322366244868556651402684641209694982590565519216188104341226838996283071654868525536914850299539675503954938371853405900096187489473992880432496373165753803673586710175783994818471798498246948060532081996066183434012476096639519778021441199752546704080608499344178256285092726523709898651539462193004607364507926212975917698293892367015170992091531567814439791248475706237804600009918293321306880570046591458387208088016887445835557926258465124763087148566313528934166117490617526671492672176128330845273936469244582892571388877839056300482483799839692029222215486145902373478222682521639957440801727144146179559226175083889020074169926238300282286249284182671243405751424188569994272331606998712986882771820617214453142574944015066139463169197629181506579745526236191224848063890033669074365989226349564114665503062965960199720636202603521917776740668777463549375318899587866282125469797102065747232721372918144666659421872003474508942830911535189271114287108376159222380276605327823351661555149369375778466670145717971901227117812780450240026384758788339396817962950690798817121690686929538248529830023476068454114178139110648560236549754227497231007615131870024053910510913817843721791422528587432098524957878034683703337818421444017138688124249984418618129271198533315382567321870421530631197748535214670955334626336610864667332292409879849256691109516143618601548909740241913509623043612196128165950518666022030715613684732364660868905014263913906515063908199378852318365059897299125404479443425166774299659811849233151555272883274028352688442408752811283289980625912673699546247341543333500147231430612750390307397135252069338173843322950701049061867539433130784798015655130384758155685236218010419650255596181934986315913233036096461905990236112681196023441843363334594927631946101716652913823717182394299216272538461776065694542297877071383198817036964588689811863210976900355735884624464835706291453052757101278872027965364479724025405448132748391794128826423835171949197209797145936887537198729130831738033911016128547415377377715951728084111627597186384924222802373441925469991983672192131287035585307966942713416391033882754318613643490100943197409047331014476299861725424423355612237435715825933382804986243892498222780715951762757847109475119033482241412025182688713728193104253478196128440176479531505057110722974314569915223451643121848657575786528197564843508958384722923534559464521215831657751471298708225909292655638836651120681943836904116252668710044560243704200663709001941185557160472044643696932850060046928140507119069261393993902735534545567470314903886022024639948260501762431969305640666366626090207048887438898907498152865444381862917382901051820869936382661868303915273264581286782806601337500096593364625146091723180312930347877421234679118454791311109897794648216922505629399956793483801699157439700537542134485874586856047286751065423341893839099110586465595113646061055156838541217459801807133163612573079611168343863767667307354583494789788316330129240800836356825939157113130978030516441716682518346573675934198084958947940983292500086389778563494693212473426103062713745077286156922596628573857905533240641849018451328284632709269753830867308409142247659474439973348130810986399417379789657010687026734161967196591599588537834822988270125605842365589539690306474965584147981310997157542043256395776070485100881578291408250777738559790129129407309462785944505859412273194812753225152324801503466519048228961406646890305102510916237770448486230229488966711380555607956620732449373374027836767300203011615227008921843515652121379215748206859356920790214502277133099987729459596952817044582181956080965811702798062669891205061560742325686842271306295009864421853470810407128917646906550836129916694778023822502789667843489199409657361704586786242554006942516693979292624714524945408858422726153755260071904336329196375777502176005195800693847635789586878489536872122898557806826518192703632099480155874455575175312736471421295536494084385586615208012115079075068553344489258693283859653013272046970694571546959353658571788894862333292465202735853188533370948455403336565356988172582528918056635488363743793348411845580168331827676834646291995605513470039147876808640322629616641560667508153710646723108461964247537490553744805318226002710216400980584497526023035640038083472053149941172965736785066421400842696497103241919182121213206939769143923368374709228267738708132236680086924703491586840991153098315412063566123187504305467536983230827966457417620806593177265685841681837966106144963432544111706941700222657817358351259821080769101961052229263879745049019254311900620561906577452416191913187533984049343976823310298465893318373015809592522829206820862230332585280119266496314441316442773003237792274712330696417149945532261035475145631290668854345426869788447742981777493710117614651624183616680254815296335308490849943006763654806102940094693750609845588558043970485914449584445079978497045583550685408745163316464118083123079704389849190506587586425810738422420591191941674182490452700288263983057950057341711487031187142834184499153456702915280104485145176055306971441761368582384102787659324662689978418319620312262421177391477208004883578333569204533935953254564897028558589735505751235129536540502842081022785248776603574246366673148680279486052445782673626230852978265057114624846595914210278122788941448163994973881884622768244851622051817076722169863265701654316919742651230041757329904473537672536845792754365412826553581858046840069367718605020070547247548400805530424951854495267247261347318174742180078574693465447136036975884118029408039616746946288540679172138601225419503819704538417268006398820656328792839582708510919958839448297775647152026132871089526163417707151642899487953564854553553148754978134009964854498635824847690590033116961303766127923464323129706628411307427046202032013368350385425360313636763575212604707425311209233402837482949453104727418969287275572027615272268283376741393425652653283068469997597097750005560889932685025049212884068274139881631540456490350775871680074055685724021758685439053228133770707415830756269628316955687424060527726485853050611356384851965918968649596335568216975437621430778665934730450164822432964891270709898076676625671517269062058815549666382573829274182082278960684488222983394816670984039024283514306813767253460126007269262969468672750794346190439996618979611928750519442356402644303271737341591281496056168353988188569484045342311424613559925272330064881627466723523751234311893442118885085079358163848994487544756331689213869675574302737953785262542329024881047181939037220666894702204258836895840939998453560948869946833852579675161882159410981624918741813364726965123980677561947912557957446471427868624053750576104204267149366084980238274680575982591331006919941904651906531171908926077949119217946407355129633864523035673345588033313197080365457184791550432654899559705862888286866606618021882248602144999973122164138170653480175510438406624412822803616648904257377640956326482825258407669045608439490325290526337532316509087681336614242398309530806549661879381949120033919489494065132398816642080088395554942237096734840072642705701165089075196155370186264797456381187856175457113400473810762763014953309735174180655479112660938034311378532532883533352024934365979129341284854970946826329075830193072665337782559314331110963848053940859283988907796210479847919686876539987477095912788727475874439806779824968278272200926449944559380414608770641941810440758269805688038949654616587983904660587645341810289907194293021774519976104495043196841503455514044820928933378657363052830619990077748726922998608279053171691876578860908941817057993404890218441559791092676862796597583952483926734883634745651687016166240642424241228961118010615682342539392180052483454723779219911228595914191877491793823340010078128326506710281781396029120914720100947878752551263372884222353869490067927664511634758101193875319657242121476038284774774571704578610417385747911301908583877890152334343013005282797038580359815182929600305682612091950943737325454171056383887047528950563961029843641360935641632589408137981511693338619797339821670761004607980096016024823096943043806956620123213650140549586250615282588033022908385812478469315720323233601899469437647726721879376826431828382603564520699468630216048874528424363593558622333506235945002890558581611275341783750455936126130852640828051213873177490200249552738734585956405160830583053770732533971552620444705429573538361113677523169972740292941674204423248113875075631319078272188864053374694213842169928862940479635305150560788126366206497231257579019598873041195626227343728900516561111094111745277965482790471250581999077498063821559376885546498822938985408291325129076478386322494781016753491693489288104203015610283386143827378160946341335383578340765314321417150655877547820252454780657301342277470616744241968952613164274104695474621483756288299771804186785084546965619150908695874251184435837306590951460980451247409411373899927822492983367796011015387096129749705566301637307202750734759922943792393824427421186158236161317886392553095117188421298508307238259729144142251579403883011359083331651858234967221259621812507058113759495525022747274674369887131926670769299199084467161228738858457584622726573330753735572823951616964175198675012681745429323738294143824814377139861906716657572945807804820559511881687188075212971832636442155336787751274766940790117057509819575084563565217389544179875074523854455200133572033332379895074393905312918212255259833790909463630202185353848854825062897715616963860712382771725621313460549401770413581731931763370136332252819127547191443450920711848838366818174263342949611870091503049165339464763717766439120798347494627397822171502090670190302469762151278521956142070806461631373236517853976292092025500288962012970141379640038055734949269073535145961208674796547733692958773628635660143767964038430796864138563447801328261284589184898528048048844180821639423974014362903481665458114454366460032490618763039502356402044530748210241366895196644221339200757479128683805175150634662569391937740283512075666260829890491877287833852178522792045771846965855278790447562192663992008409302075673925363735628390829817577902153202106409617373283598494066652141198183810884515459772895164572131897797907491941013148368544639616904607030107596818933741217575988165127000761262789169510406315857637534787420070222051070891257612361658026806815858499852631465878086616800733264676830206391697203064894405628195406190685242003053463156621891327309069687353181641094514288036605995220248248886711554429104721929134248346438705368508648749099178812670565665387191049721820042371492740164460943459845392536706132210616533085662021188968234005752675486101476993688738209584552211571923479686888160853631615862880150395949418529489227074410828207169303387818084936204018255222271010985653444817207470756019245915599431072949578197878590578940052540122867517142511184356437184053563024181225473266093302710397968091064939272722683035410467632591355279683837705019855234621222858410557119921731717969804339317707750755627056047831779844447637560254637033369247114220815519973691371975163241302748712199863404548248524570118553342675264715978310731245663429805221455494156252724028915333354349341217862037007260315279870771872491234494477147909520734761385425485311552773301030342476835865496093722324007154518129732692081058424090557725645803681462234493189708138897143299831347617799679712453782310703739151473878692119187566700319321281896803322696594459286210607438827416919465162267632540665070881071030394178860564893769816734159025925194611823642945652669372203155504700213598846292758012527715422016629954863130324912311029627923723899766416803497141226527931907636326136814145516376656559839788489381733082668779901962886932296597379951931621187215455287394170243669885593888793316744533363119541518404088283815193421234122820030950313341050704760159987985472529190665222479319715440331794836837373220821885773341623856441380700541913530245943913502554531886454796252260251762928374330465102361057583514550739443339610216229675461415781127197001738611494279501411253280621254775810512972088465263158094806633687670147310733540717710876615935856814098212967730759197382973441445256688770855324570888958320993823432102718224114763732791357568615421252849657903335093152776925505845644010552192644505312073756287744998163646332835816140330175813967359427327690448920361880386754955751806890058532927201493923500525845146706982628548257883267398735220457228239290207144822219885587102896991935873074277815159757620764023951243860202032596596250212578349957710085626386118233813318509014686577064010676278617583772772895892746039403930337271873850536912957126715066896688493880885142943609962012966759079225082275313812849851526902931700263136328942095797577959327635531162066753488651317323872438748063513314512644889967589828812925480076425186586490241111127301357197181381602583178506932244007998656635371544088454866393181708395735780799059730839094881804060935959190907473960904410150516321749681412100765719177483767355751000733616922386537429079457803200042337452807566153042929014495780629634138383551783599764708851349004856973697965238695845994595592090709058956891451141412684505462117945026611750166928260250950770778211950432617383223562437601776799362796099368975191394965033358507155418436456852616674243688920371037495328425927131610537834980740739158633817967658425258036737206469351248652238481341663808061505704829059890696451936440018597120425723007316410009916987524260377362177763430621616744884930810929901009517974541564251204822086714586849255132444266777127863728211331536224301091824391243380214046242223349153559516890816288487989988273630445372432174280215755777967021666317047969728172483392841015642274507271779269399929740308072770395013581545142494049026536105825409373114653104943382484379718606937214444600826798002471229489405761853892203425608302697052876621377373594394224114707074072902725461307358541745691419446487624357682397065703184168467540733466346293673983620004041400714054277632480132742202685393698869787607009590048684650626771363070979821006557285101306601010780633743344773073478653881742681230743766066643312775356466578603715192922768440458273283243808212841218776132042460464900801054731426749260826922155637405486241717031027919996942645620955619816454547662045022411449404749349832206807191352767986747813458203859570413466177937228534940031631599544093684089572533438702986717829770373332806801764639502090023941931499115009105276821119510999063166150311585582835582607179410052528583611369961303442790173811787412061288182062023263849861515656451230047792967563618345768105043341769543067538041113928553792529241347339481050532025708728186307291158911335942014761872664291564036371927602306283840650425441742335464549987055318726887926424102147363698625463747159744354943443899730051742525110877357886390946812096673428152585919924857640488055071329814299359911463239919113959926752576359007446572810191805841807342227734721397723218231771716916400108826112549093361186780575722391018186168549108500885272274374212086524852372456248697662245384819298671129452945515497030585919307198497105414181636968976131126744027009648667545934567059936995464500558921628047976365686133316563907395703272034389175415267500915011198856872708848195531676931681272892143031376818016445477367518353497857924276463354162433601125960252109501612264110346083465648235597934274056868849224458745493776752120324703803035491157544831295275891939893680876327685438769557694881422844311998595700727521393176837831770339130423060958999137314684569010422095161967070506420256733873446115655276175992727151877660010238944760539789516945708802728736225121076224091810066700883474737605156285533943565843756271241244457651663064085939507947550920463932245202535463634444791755661725962187199279186575490857852950012840229035061514937310107009446151011613712423761426722541732055959202782129325725947146417224977321316381845326555279604270541871496236585252458648933254145062642337885651464670604298564781968461593663288954299780722542264790400616019751975007460545150060291806638271497016110987951336633771378434416194053121445291855180136575558667615019373029691932076120009255065081583275508499340768797252369987023567931026804136745718956641431852679054717169962990363015545645090044802789055701968328313630718997699153166679208958768572290600915472919636381673596673959975710326015571920237348580521128117458610065152598883843114511894880552129145775699146577530041384717124577965048175856395072895337539755822087777506072339445587895905719156733
```

Source: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#C.23_2

Comment: You don't need the `OverflowlessStack<T>` for that sort of input, that was just there because someone was insisting that the possibility of filling the framework's stack meant that it could still "stack overflow".

Answer (score 0):

Look into tail call recursion optimization.  This will reuse the same stack frame and will not cause the overflow.  I think that all you need for this is to directly return your recursive results instead of setting them to the ans variable.

Comment: Eliminating the variable won't change anything

Answer (score 0):

I believe each thread in C# will have its own stack so if you're able to break each of these recursive calls into a new thread, you can avoid the stack overflow and probably get a new thread overflow exception instead :)